# SQL total count of another count

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table like so . . .

```
Table A
| GROUP_NAME | USERID |
| group_A | user1 |
| group_A | user2 |
| group_B | user3 |
| group_A | user4 |
| group_B | user5 |
| group_C | user6 |
| group_B | user7 |
| group_C | user8 |
| group_C | user9 |
| group_A | user10 |
```

What I want is the total number of rows where total number of userids in a any particular group is less than or greater than a certain number.

The closest I can come is something like this:

```
select count(distinct group_name)
from Table_A
group by userid having count(*) < 5;
```

. . . but this give me a separate row for each result.

What I want is a total count of all rows that are returned.

This is for a table in an Oracle database.

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want total number of users in the groups where count of users in that group is less than 5(say), use

```
SELECT group_name,
       COUNT(userid)
  FROM table_a
 GROUP BY group_name
HAVING COUNT(userid) < 5;
```

For total number of distinct users, use

```
SELECT group_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT userid)
  FROM table_a
 GROUP BY group_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) < 5;
```

Total number of rows returned from above query, then use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM (SELECT group_name,
               COUNT(DISTINCT userid)
          FROM table_a
         GROUP BY group_name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) < 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use **COUNT() OVER()** analytic function.

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (GROUP_NAME varchar2(7), USERID varchar2(6))
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
  3           VALUES ('group_A', 'user1')
  4      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
  5           VALUES ('group_A', 'user2')
  6      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
  7           VALUES ('group_B', 'user3')
  8      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
  9           VALUES ('group_A', 'user4')
 10      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 11           VALUES ('group_B', 'user5')
 12      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 13           VALUES ('group_C', 'user6')
 14      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 15           VALUES ('group_B', 'user7')
 16      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 17           VALUES ('group_C', 'user8')
 18      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 19           VALUES ('group_C', 'user9')
 20      INTO t (GROUP_NAME, USERID)
 21           VALUES ('group_A', 'user10')
 22  SELECT * FROM dual
 23  ;

10 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT t.*,
  2      COUNT(GROUP_NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_NAME ORDER BY GROUP_NAME) cnt
  3    FROM t;

GROUP_N USERID        CNT
------- ------ ----------
group_A user10          4
group_A user2           4
group_A user1           4
group_A user4           4
group_B user3           3
group_B user5           3
group_B user7           3
group_C user8           3
group_C user9           3
group_C user6           3

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

To **filter** out the rows having lesser count than desired:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT t.*,
  3      COUNT(GROUP_NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_NAME ORDER BY GROUP_NAME) cnt
  4    FROM t
  5    )
  6  SELECT GROUP_NAME, USERID FROM DATA WHERE cnt < 4;

GROUP_N USERID
------- ------
group_B user3
group_B user5
group_B user7
group_C user8
group_C user9
group_C user6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**Update** As per OP's request in the comments:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT t.*,
  3      COUNT(GROUP_NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_NAME ORDER BY GROUP_NAME) cnt
  4    FROM t
  5    )
  6  SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name) cnt FROM DATA WHERE cnt < 4;

       CNT
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: +One for the way you explain your solutions which is in a detailed manner.

Comment: Yes, you're close and this is where I can get to as well. What I want from here though is just a total count of all distinct groups from the list your query returns. So for example in your last example where 6 rows are returned, there are two distinct group names that have userids < 4, so my expected query return would be a count of 2.

Comment: @Kawili-wili, Ok, in that case you just need to do the count. See my update in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select count(distinct group_name) from Table_A  having count(*) < 5;
```

Comment: Exactl,y since he was grouping which was returning multiple rows..this query would return the total number.

Comment: Returns nothing. I want to find groups that have less than 5 userids. Not sure how your query will do that if it never looks at the userid column.

Comment: try this ->  select total from (
select group_name,count(*)  as total from Table_A group by userid
) as alias  ... and please let me know where it worked or not

Comment: @Kawili-wili, a query does not need to look at the userid coulmn, because you really need to count how many times this group is repeated. That's all!

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, based on OP comment, i'd suggest to remove `distinct` keyword.

Comment: seems like he needs to select all the groups where user count is less than 5

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to group by group_name instead:

```
select count(1) as nr_of_users, group_name 
  from table_a 
 group by group_name 
having count(1) < 4
```

and if you want to total the nr of rows, use it as subquery:

```
select count(1) from (
    select count(1) as nr_of_users, group_name 
      from table_a 
     group by group_name 
    having count(1) < 4
) as a
```